# ChromeDriver doesn't click on element. Selenium. Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am making scenario to automatizate some actions on this site https://csgo500.com/

Code of my class:

```
package scenario;

import managers.loaders.CheckBy;
import driver.sleep.DriverSleeper;
import exceptions.NotNowException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class CSGO500Scen implements SiteScenarioInt{
    private WebDriver driver;

    public CSGO500Scen(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void gamble() throws NotNowException {
        driver.get("https://csgo500.com/");

        CheckBy.id("gotit-btn");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gotit-btn")).click(); //accept terms of use
        DriverSleeper.sleep(3);

        CheckBy.id("content-login");
        DriverSleeper.sleep(3);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content-login\"]")).click(); //HERE IS A PROBLEM

        CheckBy.className("btn_green_white_innerfade");
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn_green_white_innerfade")).click(); //login with steam

        CheckBy.className("nav-rewards");
        driver.findElement(By.className("nav-rewards")).click();

        if(!isActive()){
            throw new NotNowException("CSGO500.com");
        }
        else{
            while(true){
                DriverSleeper.sleep(3);
                if (!isActive()){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isActive(){
        if (driver.findElement(By.id("reward-claim-submit-disabled")).getAttribute("style").equals("display: none;")){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

First step is to Accept Use Terms. Ok, it's done, but when i want to click on "Login" button, i get following error(Login button id is "content-login") :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a id="content-login" href="https://www.csgo-xchange.com/steam" data-lang="login" class="" data-__original="
...
" data-__trid="1000018" data-__translated="en">Login</a> is not clickable at point (946, 33). Other element would receive the click: <div id="login-content">...</div>
```

It writes that this page contains one more element with the same id.
I have written Test to get number of elements with this id:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\sitescen\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe" );
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.csgo500.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.print(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content-login\"]")).size());

    }
}
```

I got output:

```
1
```

So, i have only one element with the same id, and no elements arround this button.

To prevent errors of loading, i use `sleep` of my `DriverSleeper` class which accept number of seconds to sleep.

Finally, i don't know, how to click this button, and hope, that you help me.

UPD: Class where i call gamble method:

```
public class Coleso {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\sitescen\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe" );
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        DriverSleeper.setDriver(driver);
        CheckBy.setDriver(driver);
        SteamLogin log = new SteamLogin(driver);
        CSGO500Scen site = new CSGO500Scen(driver);
        try {
            site.gamble();
        } catch (NotNowException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you consider showing us the `SiteScenarioInt` class please? Thanks

Comment: it is just interface
`package scenario;

import exceptions.NotNowException;

public interface SiteScenarioInt{
    public void gamble() throws NotNowException;

}
`

Comment: But then how do I resolve `CheckBy`, `DriverSleeper`, & `NotNowException` ? Thanks

Comment: Try scrolling to the element you are trying to `.click()`. Alternatively, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have problem in your xpath. You need to change this  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content-login\"]")).click();`

to

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content-login']")).click();
```

**UPDATE:**

if `webdriver click()` isn't working then try clicking using `JavascriptExecutor` as following:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content-login']")));
```

Comment: @Oleg_Hudyma : I've update my answer try the solution provided in UPDATED section. Works well on my machine.

Comment: ty, works perfectly! Can i you JS executer for every element? is it better than clicking with driver?

Comment: It is not recommended to use JavascriptExecutor for automation purposes, but who is to stop you ;)

Comment: so style of my code is good? i'm not tester, but i can't create this functionality in another way

Comment: yes @Oleg_Hudyma. also, don't forget to upvote my answer.

Comment: y upvote youe answer, but i don't have enough rep to get it shown

Comment: Becausr I thought you downvoted it, and now it works for you.